# Neural Networks with Input 0

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Imagine you have a Neural Network with Sigmoids. It has an input $x$ and so a node would output $\tanh x$ to a connection. The connection would then output $w*tanhx$  where $w$ is the weight of the connection.

The problem is, what if an input is 0 and the desire output should be something like 1? Well if the input is 0, the output of the connection would be $w*tanh0 = 0$. So if the input is 0, then then output will always be 0 no matter how many nodes or connections you add or how much the weights on the connections are.

How would you make a simple network where an input of 0 will give you something other than 0?

Answer (score 5):

That's why you need the bias term $b$, then the output will be like $tanh(wx+b)$.
When the input is 0, the output will be $tanh(b)$ instead of 0.